# Making Skype calls over Amazon Fire TV Stick

Tags: skype, video-conference, amazon-fire-tv-stick

**Making Skype calls through Amazon Fire TV Stick**

I have a Samsung Smart TV which does not use Android; I thought all smart TVs were Android and the return date had passed. To get around this, what I propose is to use an Amazon Fire TV Stick. Amazon Fire TV Stick has a power USB port which I link to something [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96jycuEMm2k) where a USB hub could be used to add a camera and microphone.

I was wondering if this system would work to make video calls with Skype on Fire TV Stick.

I understand that even if my TV was an Android TV, Skype has discontinued its services on smart TVs. However, I really want to know if this system would work because then I could also use it on other conferencing software like Zoom.